# Map mixed data in vertical columns in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't found any solution for the following problem:

I have a sheet with a single row of data with a unique ID, see below:

[image: input data]

Question: How can i get the data organized like below? The name before the colon will be mapped to the row header like in the image.

[image: results data]

Comment: You can do so by using VBA.

Comment: What if an ID have two values for same header as in the case of `ID 004` with two `Transmission`?

Comment: Mrig: The double value ID in ID 004 can be ignored, thats my fault with the example sheet. All the values in a raw are single.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below assumes:

- The number of columns in the input data is known (the solution assumes 5 columns are required after the `Unique ID` column)
- The "attributes" ie the column headings to be used in the output is a known list
- If an attribute appears more than once in an input row, only the value associated with the leftmost occurrence is used (see comment by Mrig)

[image]

The solution uses 8 basic Excel functions: `FIND(), LEFT(), RIGHT(), TRIM(), LEN(), INDEX(), MATCH() and IFERROR()`. If you want to understand how the solution works then you will need to understand these individual functions and what they do. The functions are combined into 3 basic formula for: (1) extracting the *attribute* part of the *attribute:value* pairs in the input data; (2) extracting the *value* part; and (3) getting the correct *value* into each of the output columns.

Comment: DMM: I am working on it, i understand what you are doing, i will post when i am done. Thx in advance